# How do I pass the value of an HTML property to a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I would like to pass the value of an HTML tag to a jQuery alert box, but I'm not getting any luck. I basically want to pass either "1" or "2" to the alert box. I keep getting "undefined" in the alert box.

```
<button class="up" value="1">
<button class="down" value="2">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up,.down").click(function(){
        alert(this.value);
   });
)};
```

I'm doing this for an ajax function, but I need to make sure I can pass the values first, so the alert box is for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the value of a button is what's *between* the `<button></button>` tags in **IE7**, to be safe you can instead you can use for example a `data-` attribute, like this:

```
<button class="up" data-value="1">Something</button>
```

With matching script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".up,.down").click(function(){
        alert($(this).data("value"));
   });
)};
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/z97gr/2/).

Comment: Thanks, Nick. One thing: why will this alert "undefined?" myData = $(this).data("value"); alert(myData);

Comment: @Mel - If you're not on jQuery 1.4.3+ use `.attr("data-value")`...otherwise `.data("value")` will pull it correctly.

Comment: Never mind... the var has to be defined inside the click function!

Answer (score 4):

```
alert($(this).attr("value"));
```

Comment: This should make no difference, and still doesn't address the IE7 issue here.

Answer (score 2):

`this.value` works just fine (I [tested it](http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/c8a5c/1/) in IE8, FF3, and Chrome).  Not sure how you can possibly be seeing "undefined".  You do have a syntax error in the closing of your document.ready handler.  It should be `});` and not `)};`

EDIT: I believe Nick Craver on the IE7 bug, and I think aside from using a custom attribute in the markup you could do the following...

```
$(".up,.down").click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var oldText = $this.text();
  $this.text('');
  var val = this.value;
  $this.text(oldText);
  alert(val);
});
```

[Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/c8a5c/1/) if you have IE7 please!

Comment: In IE7 the `value` is the text between the tags, it's not safe to use a `value` attribute here. For example: http://allinthehead.com/retro/330/coping-with-internet-explorers-mishandling-of-buttons

Comment: @Nick Interesting.  I'll take your word for it; I don't have a simple way to test IE7 right now.

Comment: In it's defense...it does predate the `<button>` element, but that doesn't make it any less of a PITA to deal with if you're supporting it

Comment: Josh - Confirmed your fix works. Also, IE7 correctly reports the `value` property *if there is no text content*. So if perhaps the buttons are empty and are styled with CSS, then it may work. Although if I remember correctly, Firefox has some difficulties with styled `<button>` elements.